# SEO/performance - building blog article page

Tags: html, performance, url-rewriting, seo, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I've been using WP up and until now, but want to spread my wings and build a bespoke blog for my website. The reason I want my own blog is that I cannot get my WP site to match the branding/design of my main website, and because my blog is very basic, there is a ton of stuff on WP that I really don't need.

I'm using ASP/Windows IIS7 and the URL rewrite module, which is all working fine (tested), plus I've built my database and administration pages.

I'm now about to tackle the article page itself. Before I get started with it, I would like to hear some suggestions/ideas/tips on building the page correctly, mainly for enhancing SEO rankings, but for general performance too.

I know using heading tags (h1-h6), paragraph tags (p), and alt/title attributes will enhance rankings if used correctly. I'm also familiar with meta keywords and description tags, especially being dynamically produced.

What other building requirements are there that will help with successful SE ranking and general performance? Is there anything else I should be aware of when building this article page? And also, I'm not bothered that my user cannot remember the URL of the page, but will using a URL like www.mydomain.com/articles/12334435544 be a problem to SE's, using only numbers (representing article ID) and no text?

Comment: 1 person down-voted and 2 people have voted to close it, all without writing a comment or reason. It's you moderators that need moderating, how hard is it for you to give a reason, so I can write my next question correctly? And it's not off-topic, it's a programming related question about a blog page

Comment: You're talking about HTML tags and URL rewrite rules, seems like valid question to me. Nothing off-topic about that in my eyes.

Comment: Your main topic is SEO, not programming.